# Replacing Rackspace Cloud SITES with Amazon EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, rackspace, sites

So at work we run a bunch of sites on rackspaces cloud sites platform. This works alright, except I have no way of tweaking anything server side and I find that they sometimes aren't as responsive as they could be.

Let's assume that most of the sites are bloated wordpress installations.

Would it be possible to use EC2 micro instances to host these? (One instance per site)?

I want to move away from rackspace as I have no flexibility with cloud sites and prefer Amazons services.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! You can easily do that!

1. Sign up for EC2 [here](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).
2. Go to http://alestic.com/ and chose AMI (Ubuntu AMIs for EC2 drop-down) you want to start instance from.
3. Start EC2 Micro Instance by hitting the links (or use [API Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351)). You can use user-data to install desired software on instance start, but I recommend (for simplicity) just to start Instance and install software via terminal using SSH. Follow the dialog and create RSA key to connect your Instance.
4. Connect to your Instance over ssh using RSA key.
5. Install software. For example: `sudo su`, then `apt-get update && apt-get install -y ntp php5-fpm nginx wordpress [...]`.
6. Create AMI from running Instance with installed and configured software.
7. Launch more Instances from your own AMI bundled with Wordpress and stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I am a rackspace employee.

If you want more flexibility than rackspace cloud sites, then you can use rackspace cloud server. You will have all the flexibility of the cloud. If you like the managed part of cloud sites, then i would suggest managed cloud server.